# Dir.entries(src).sort.each do |item| in natural order

Tags: ruby, macos, sorting

File names look like `1835 Some text. p1`, `1835 Some text. p1035`, `1835 Some text. p2`

I want the files to be processed in natural order, but Ruby sorts in binary order so p1035 comes before p2. Can this be done in natural order using something like `Dir.entries(src).sort.each do |item|`?

I would like to process .jpg files and change the creation date according to the p(age) order. For example the files above will have creation dates of `1897-01-01 00:00:**01** -0800`, `1897-01-01 00:00:**02** -0800` etc. That is the seconds are incremented so they appear in order in a photo management program and show up in the calendar in that program.

On macOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to @Schwern

```
Dir.chdir(src)  # the directory
files = Dir.glob("*.{jpg,png}")
filesSorted = Naturally.sort(files)
filesSorted.each do |item|
  fn = src + item
  # process each file
end
```

This has a small advantage over `Dir.entries(src).each` because Dir.glob doesn't seem to pick up the . and .. files.

Comment: 1) Avoid `Dir.chdir` without a block, it changes the global state of the program. Use it with a block to ensure don't unexpectedly wind up in a different directory. 2) Since you've changed directories there should be no need to add the directory onto the filename. 3) [Pathname](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.4/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) is more convenient than File and Dir because you're working with objects, not strings. `require 'pathname'; files = Pathname(src).glob("*.{jpg,png}"); Naturally.sort(files).each { |file| ... }`

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I think for my limited case it's OK. But your suggestion should be more robust. Except, `files: [#<Pathname:/Users/gscar/Documents/Genealogy/City Directories/1` isn't as accesible.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't as accessible"?

Comment: If I did what you suggested correctly files doesn't work in the .each loop. In my previous post I showed the result for the first file.

Comment: `Naturally.sort(files).each { |file| puts file }` to show each file sorted naturally, for example.

Comment: Your question was about natural sorting. Now it seems to be about your specific use of files and sorted arrays, and perhaps you're still learning Ruby basics? You're probably best to ask another quesition and leave this one about natural sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [naturally](https://github.com/dogweather/naturally).

```
$ gem install naturally
Fetching naturally-2.2.1.gem
Successfully installed naturally-2.2.1
Parsing documentation for naturally-2.2.1
Installing ri documentation for naturally-2.2.1
Done installing documentation for naturally after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

$ irb
2.7.4 :001 > require 'naturally'
 => true 
2.7.4 :002 > Naturally.sort(['1835 Some text. p1', '1835 Some text. p1035', '1835 Some text. p2'])
 => ["1835 Some text. p1", "1835 Some text. p2", "1835 Some text. p1035"] 
2.7.4 :003 > Naturally.sort(["336", "335a", "3356", "335.1"])
 => ["335.1", "335a", "336", "3356"]
```

Comment: files = ['1835 Some text. p1', '1835 Some text. p1035', '1835 Some text. p2']

Naturally.sort(files)

=> ["1835 Some text. p1", "1835 Some text. p1035", "1835 Some text. p2"]
Nothing changes. Maybe format is wrong.

Comment: files = ["336", "335a", "3356", "335.1"]  # => ["336", "335a", "3356", "335.1"]. Without delving into the gem, it is limited. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: @Greg Works For Me™ Perhaps you're expecting it to sort in place? It returns a new sorted Array.

Comment: My mistake. Sorry. Duh

Maybe this should be a new question, but can I combine 'naturally' with `Dir.entries(src).each do |item|`? I could work through creating file names from the array, but that and then doing the processing, etc.